# Displaying Return Values of Functions in SelectList in VisualForce

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

In my controller, I have this function, which calls a utility function to get all subordinate users to the currently logged in user:

```
public string getUsers() {

  Set<Id> userlist = new Set<Id>();
  userlist.add(UserInfo.getUserId());
  userlist.addAll(RoleUtils.getRoleSubordinateUsers(UserInfo.getUserId()));

  String retValue = ':All;';
  Integer iCount = 0;

  for (User usr: [select Name from User where Id in :userlist and isActive = true and      Employee_Group__c like '%Sales%' order by Name]) {
    retValue += usr.Name + ':' + usr.Name;

    iCount++;

    if (iCount < userlist.size()) {
       retValue += ';';
    }
  }

  return retValue;
}
```

How can I display the `retValue`, which is the list of users, in a `SelectList` on my VFPage?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your users to a select list like this:

```
userList = new List<SelectOption>():
for (User usr: [select Name from User where Id in ... order by Name]) {
    userList.add(new SelectOption(usr.Id + ':' + usr.Name);
} 
return userList;
```

You'll also need to change the function to return the correct type:

```
public List<selectoption> getUsers() {
```

Which can then be consumed by the Visualforce select list.